# DBUnit, JUnit, PostgreSQL, Maven, and H2 in-memory setup

Tags: junit, h2, dbunit, in-memory

I'm trying to do something simple---what I assumed would be the most simple thing to do with DBUnit---and I admit I'm lost.

I just want to load a DBUnit database state into an in-memory H2 database so I can run tests on the H2 database.

In Maven I manually use `dbunit-maven-plugin` with `PostgresqlDataTypeFactory` to generate `dbunit.xml` from an existing database. But this flat file XML database indicates no column types whatsoever. **Should the DBUnit database dump in XML contain type information?**

Following the online instructions, I try to create a JUnit test to simply load that XML file:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setupDBUnit() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, DatabaseUnitException {
  Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
  Connection jdbcConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:foo");
  IDatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection(jdbcConnection);
  IDataSet dataSet=new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(FooTest.class.getResourceAsStream("dbunit.xml"));
  try {
    DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(connection, dataSet);
  } finally {
    connection.close();
  }
}
```

I put in a fake test and run the test. I get a lot of debug statements; it seems like it's reading something, although I see no values I recognize:

```
09:55:29.802 [main] DEBUG o.dbunit.dataset.OrderedTableNameMap - getTableName(tableName=value) - start
09:55:29.802 [main] DEBUG o.dbunit.dataset.OrderedTableNameMap - getTableName(tableName=value) - end - result=VALUE
09:55:29.802 [main] DEBUG o.dbunit.dataset.OrderedTableNameMap - getTableName(tableName=VALUE) - start
09:55:29.802 [main] DEBUG o.dbunit.dataset.OrderedTableNameMap - getTableName(tableName=VALUE) - end - result=VALUE
09:55:29.802 [main] DEBUG org.dbunit.dataset.CachedDataSet - startTable(metaData=tableName=value, columns=[], keys=[]) - start
09:55:29.802 [main] DEBUG o.dbunit.dataset.xml.FlatXmlProducer - endElement(uri=, localName=, qName=value) - start
09:55:29.802 [main] DEBUG o.dbunit.dataset.xml.FlatXmlProducer - startElement(uri=, localName=, qName=value, attributes=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser$AttributesProxy@63e2203c) - start
09:55:29.802 [main] DEBUG o.dbunit.dataset.OrderedTableNameMap - getLastTableName() - start
09:55:29.802 [main] DEBUG o.dbunit.dataset.OrderedTableNameMap - getTableName(tableName=value) - start
09:55:29.802 [main] DEBUG o.dbunit.dataset.OrderedTableNameMap - getTableName(tableName=value) - end - result=VALUE
...
```

Then it starts initializing the data, but there are `null` values that are obviously incorrect:

```
09:55:29.851 [main] DEBUG org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet - getTableMetaData(tableName=null) - start
09:55:29.851 [main] DEBUG org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet - initialize() - start
09:55:29.851 [main] DEBUG org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet - Initializing the data set from the database...
09:55:29.876 [main] DEBUG org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet - 
    database product name=H2
    database version=1.4.184 (2014-12-19)
    database major version=1
    database minor version=4
    jdbc driver name=H2 JDBC Driver
    jdbc driver version=1.4.184 (2014-12-19)
    jdbc driver major version=1
    jdbc driver minor version=4

09:55:29.876 [main] DEBUG org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet - metadata resultset=rs0: org.h2.result.LocalResult@27f723 columns: 11 rows: 0 pos: -1
09:55:29.876 [main] DEBUG o.dbunit.dataset.OrderedTableNameMap - getTableName(tableName=null) - start
09:55:29.876 [main] DEBUG o.dbunit.dataset.OrderedTableNameMap - getTableName(tableName=null) - end - result=NULL
09:55:29.876 [main] ERROR org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet - Table 'null' not found in tableMap=org.dbunit.dataset.OrderedTableNameMap[_tableNames=[], _tableMap={}, _caseSensitiveTableNames=false]
09:55:29.876 [main] DEBUG o.d.d.s.AbstractBatchStatement - close() - start
09:55:29.876 [main] DEBUG o.dbunit.database.DatabaseConnection - close() - start
```

**Why am I getting an error `Table 'null' not found in tableMap`?**

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, apparently [DBUnit does not save and load the database schema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1531363/421049) (i.e. no column type information is included), making it far less useful than I had assumed. Maybe that was the source of the `Table 'null'...` error, as well---I don't know.

Now I have to figure out how to easily dump my PostgreSQL schema and get it into H2 for in-memory testing. Maybe I can use [`Runscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10679673/421049) for this, if I can tease out my PostgreSQL schema initialization statement. In any case, DBUnit wasn't as easy a dump/load testing tool as I had hoped.