# dbunit not able to read data from dataset.xml

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, integration-testing, dbunit

I am trying to run a dbunit test case by loading data from an xml file (dataset.xml) and the program fails to find the table. I am new to dbunit and lack of good working examples is preventing me from running a simple program. Can anybody please guide on this?

**Error Log**

```
SEVERE: Table 'states' not found in tableMap=org.dbunit.dataset.OrderedTableNameMap[_tableNames=[], _tableMap={}, _caseSensitiveTableNames=false]
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.64 sec <<< FAILURE!
testMe(com.istore.dao.DatabaseXmlTest)  Time elapsed: 0.579 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchTableException: states
    at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.getTableMetaData(DatabaseDataSet.java:288)
    at org.dbunit.operation.DeleteAllOperation.execute(DeleteAllOperation.java:109)
    at org.dbunit.operation.CompositeOperation.execute(CompositeOperation.java:79)
    at org.dbunit.AbstractDatabaseTester.executeOperation(AbstractDatabaseTester.java:190)
    at org.dbunit.AbstractDatabaseTester.onSetup(AbstractDatabaseTester.java:103)
    at org.dbunit.DatabaseTestCase.setUp(DatabaseTestCase.java:156)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:139)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)


Results :

Tests in error: 
  testMe(com.istore.dao.DatabaseXmlTest): states
```

**dataset.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
    <states state_id="1" state_cd="NJ" name="New Jersey" tax_pct="6" active="Y"/>
    <states state_id="2" state_cd="PA" name="Pennsylvania" tax_pct="6" active="Y"/>
</dataset>
```

**DatabaseXmlTest.java**

```
public class DatabaseXmlTest extends DataSourceBasedDBTestCase {

    public static final String url = "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:my-project-test;shutdown=true";
    public static final String driver = "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver";
    public static final String user = "";
    public static final String pwd = "";

    @Override
    protected DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driver);
        dataSource.setUsername(user);
        dataSource.setPassword(pwd);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    protected IDataSet getDataSet() throws Exception {
        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/dataset.xml");
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        FlatXmlDataSet dataset = new FlatXmlDataSet(reader);
        return dataset;
    }

    public void testMe() throws Exception {
        DataSource dataSource = getDataSource();
        HsqldbConnection cn = new HsqldbConnection(dataSource.getConnection(), null);
        DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(cn, getDataSet());
        //get all states
        List<State> states = new StateDao(dataSource).getAllStates();
        assertNotNull(states);
    }

}
```

**StateDao.java**

```
public class StateDao {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(StateDao.class);

    protected DataSource dataSource;

    public StateDao(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public List<State> getAllStates() throws SQLException {
        String sql = "select * from states a where a.active='Y'";
        StateQueryExecutor executor = new StateQueryExecutor(dataSource.getConnection(), sql);
        List<State> states = executor.getAllStates();
        LOG.debug("states = " + states);
        return states;
    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531324/is-there-any-way-for-dbunit-to-automatically-create-tables

Comment: Does the table exist before running the test? Have you tried annotating the test class like this: `@DatabaseSetup("dataset.xml")` ?