# Not able to read a dataset from xml using dbunit and h2 database

Tags: java, unit-testing, dbunit

I am getting `NoSuchTableException` exception when dbunit tries to read data from an XML file. Initially I thought this issue is related to HSQLDB and hence switched to H2 database but the issue persists. I am new to dbunit and cannot get some good up to date documentation on this. All the tutorial found online are with really older versions of dbunit and not descriptive enough.

Not sure what's going on here. Can anyone please guide me as to what's wrong with this program ?

**Error Log**

```
SEVERE: Table 'users' not found in tableMap=org.dbunit.dataset.OrderedTableNameMap[_tableNames=[], _tableMap={}, _caseSensitiveTableNames=false]
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.493 sec <<< FAILURE!
testGetUser(com.istore.dao.UserDaoTest)  Time elapsed: 0.42 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchTableException: users
    at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.getTableMetaData(DatabaseDataSet.java:288)
    at org.dbunit.operation.DeleteAllOperation.execute(DeleteAllOperation.java:109)
    at org.dbunit.operation.CompositeOperation.execute(CompositeOperation.java:79)
    at org.dbunit.AbstractDatabaseTester.executeOperation(AbstractDatabaseTester.java:190)
    at org.dbunit.AbstractDatabaseTester.onSetup(AbstractDatabaseTester.java:103)
```

pom.xml

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.187</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**src/test/resources/users.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
    <users id="1" name="Nital"/>
</dataset>
```

**AbstractUserDaoTest.java**

```
public class AbstractUserDaoTest extends DataSourceBasedDBTestCase {

    private static final String USERS_DATASET = "/users.xml";
    private static final UserDao dao = new UserDao();
    protected static Connection connection;
    protected static HsqldbConnection dbunitConnection;

    @Override
    protected DataSource getDataSource() {
        //create datasource
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:test");
        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    protected IDataSet getDataSet() throws Exception {
        String fileName = getClass().getResource(USERS_DATASET).getFile();
        System.out.println("fileName = " + fileName);
        FlatXmlDataSet dataset = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(new FileInputStream(fileName));
        System.out.println("dataset = " + dataset);
        String[] tableNames = dataset.getTableNames();
        for (String t : tableNames) {
            System.out.println("t = " + t);
        }
        return dataset;
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void closeDatabase() throws Exception {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
            connection = null;
        }
        if (dbunitConnection != null) {
            dbunitConnection.close();
            dbunitConnection = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**UserDaoTest.java**

```
public class UserDaoTest extends AbstractUserDaoTest {
    @Test
    public void testGetUser() {
        String a = "abc";
        assertNotNull(a);
    }
}
```

**UserDao.java**

```
public class UserDao extends BaseDao {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(UserDao.class);

    public UserDao() {
    }

    public UserDao(DataSource dataSource) throws SQLException {
        super(dataSource);
    }

    public User getUser(String userCd) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "select * from users a where a.user_cd='" + userCd + "' and a.active='Y'";
        System.out.println("sql = " + sql);
        UserQueryExecutor executor = new UserQueryExecutor(dataSource.getConnection(), sql);
        User user = executor.getUser();
        LOG.debug("user = " + user);
        return user;
    }

    //used in dbunit tests
    public boolean createTable() throws SQLException {
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE users (" +
                    "  id  INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1)," +
                    "  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL) ";
        System.out.println("sql = " + sql);
        System.out.println("cn = " + dataSource.getConnection());
        UserQueryExecutor queryExecutor = new UserQueryExecutor(dataSource.getConnection(), sql);
        boolean success = queryExecutor.createTable();
        System.out.println("success = " + success);
        return success;
    }

}
```

**BaseDao.java**

```
public class BaseDao {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(BaseDao.class);

    protected DataSource dataSource;
    //using this field for dbunit tests, otherwise dataSource will be sufficient
    protected Connection connection;

    public BaseDao() {
    }

    public BaseDao(DataSource dataSource) throws SQLException {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    //used only for dbunit tests
    public void setConnection(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

}
```

**UserQueryExecutor.java**

```
public final class UserQueryExecutor extends BaseQueryExecutor {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(UserQueryExecutor.class);

    public UserQueryExecutor(Connection cn, String sql) {
        super(cn, sql);
    }

    public User getUser() {
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        User user = null;

        LOG.debug(sql);

        try {
            stmt = cn.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs != null && rs.next()) {
                user = new DataPopulator().populateUser(rs);
            }
            LOG.debug("user = " + user);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            LOG.error("Exception whiile fetching data for a user.......", ex);
        } finally {
            DbUtils.closeQuietly(cn, stmt, rs);
        }
        return user;
    }

    public boolean createTable() {
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        boolean tableCreated = false;

        LOG.debug(sql);

        try {
            stmt = cn.createStatement();
            tableCreated = stmt.execute(sql);
            LOG.debug("tableCreated = " + tableCreated);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            LOG.error("Exception whiile creating user table.......", ex);
        } finally {
            DbUtils.closeQuietly(cn, stmt, rs);
        }
        return tableCreated;
    }

}
```

**BaseQueryExecutor.java**

```
public class BaseQueryExecutor {

    protected Connection cn;
    protected String sql;

    public BaseQueryExecutor(Connection cn, String sql) {
        this.cn = cn;
        this.sql = sql;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`DBUnit` doesn't create the database tables automatically from the XML Dataset because it hasn't enough information.
Unless I'm mistaken, you don't call the method `createTable()` of your `UserQueryExecutor` anywhere.

So, you have to execute an script to create the database schema before testing (typically you can do it in the setUp method). There is more info in other SO questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531324/is-there-any-way-for-dbunit-to-automatically-create-tables)

Hope it helps.